# How can the text of a subsection title in a report be set to one thing in the body of the report and set to another thing in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, bold, report

I have a subsection title like this:

```
\subsection{${\boldsymbol{b}}$-tagging}
```

As this is bold in the main body of the report, it looks fine, but in the table of contents, which are not bold for subsections, the "b" at the start remains bold, when it should really not be bold, as follows:

```
\subsection{${b}$-tagging}
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: You should never include formatting commands directly in the argument of \section, \subsection, &c. A work-around: use the optional argument of \subsection without `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: Use the optional argument `\subsection[text for toc]{text for main document}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah thanks for that, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Bernard As far as I am aware, LaTeX does not have the ability inbuilt to switch selections of text and mathematics together between bold and not bold, even though this would be consistent with the spirit of LaTeX. Your suggestion of not using `\boldsymbol` would make both both and not bold characters appear together in a title that should be bold, which isn't acceptable.

Comment: It os possible using titlesec, if I understand well what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sectional units `\<sec unit>[<ToC text>]{<body text>}` are defined to take an optional argument that represents the `<ToC text>` which may be different from the `<body text>`. If you are additionally loading [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), you have to use `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}` to distinguish between content that may end up in the document itself or the PDF bookmarks:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section
  [ToC section] % ToC text
  {A section} % Body text
\subsection
  [A subsection \texorpdfstring{$b$}{b}] % ToC text
  {A subsection $\boldsymbol{b}$} % Body text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many journals do not make mathematics bold in title as in many disciplines the bold letters have different meaning, however it's also reasonable to do so, especially if there is an extra bold font for use to denote the bold math alphabet in contexts that are already bold.

So you could use

```
\subsection[$b$-tagging]{${\boldsymbol{b}}$-tagging}
```

But it's slightly dubious markup, really the decision to use or not use bold in titles should be a document-wide setting. If you want text and math to both be bold then you need to set `\boldmath` as well as `\bfseries`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

% from report.cls
%\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
%                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
%                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
%                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\boldmath\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\subsection{$b$-tagging}
zzzzzzzz $b$-tagging zzzz

\end{document}
```